# After success deploy on heroku, still not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was deploy my ROR app to heroku.

My steps:

1. heroku login
2. using gem 'pg' and postgres db
3. git init   git add .
4. git commit -m "init"
5. heroku create my_app
6. git push heroku master

   - Counting objects: 7, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
   - Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done. Writing objects: 100% (4/4),
   - 422 bytes, done. Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
   - -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
   - -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
   - Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment

     - Using rake (10.0.3)
     - Using i18n (0.6.4)
     - Using multi_json (1.6.1)
     - Using activesupport (3.2.8)
     - Using builder (3.0.4)
     - Using activemodel (3.2.8)
     - Using erubis (2.7.0)
     - Using journey (1.0.4)
     - Using rack (1.4.5)
     - Using rack-cache (1.2)
     - Using rack-test (0.6.2)
     - Using hike (1.2.1)
     - Using tilt (1.3.4)
     - Using sprockets (2.1.3)
     - Using actionpack (3.2.8)
     - Using mime-types (1.21)
     - Using polyglot (0.3.3)
     - Using treetop (1.4.12)
     - Using mail (2.4.4)
     - Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
     - Using arel (3.0.2)
     - Using tzinfo (0.3.36)
     - Using activerecord (3.2.8)
     - Using activeresource (3.2.8)
     - Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
     - Using breadcrumbs_on_rails (2.3.0)
     - Using orm_adapter (0.4.0)
     - Using ckeditor (4.0.2)
     - Using coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
     - Using execjs (1.4.0)
     - Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
     - Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
     - Using json (1.7.7)
     - Using rdoc (3.12.2)
     - Using thor (0.17.0)
     - Using railties (3.2.8)
     - Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
     - Using daemons (1.1.9)
     - Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5)
     - Using rails (3.2.8)
     - Using datagrid (0.7.1)
     - Using warden (1.2.1)
     - Using devise (2.2.3)
     - Using dragonfly (0.9.14)
     - Using eventmachine (1.0.1)
     - Using galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3)
     - Using has_scope (0.5.1)
     - Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
     - Using ledermann-rails-settings (1.2.1)
     - Using nokogiri (1.5.6)
     - Using pg (0.14.1)
     - Using rails-settings (1.0.0)
     - Using recaptcha (0.3.5)
     - Using rest-client (1.6.7)
     - Using rmagick (2.13.1)
     - Using russian (0.6.0)
     - Using sass (3.2.6)
     - Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
     - Using sequel (3.20.0)
     - Using simple-navigation (3.10.0)
     - Using sinatra (1.0)
     - Using taps (0.3.24)
     - Using thin (1.5.0)
     - Using uglifier (1.3.0)
     - Using will_paginate (3.0.4)
     - Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
     - Cleaning up the bundler cache.

       - -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       - -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
     - Running: rake assets:precompile
     - Asset precompilation completed (206.35s)

       - -----> Rails plugin injection
     - Injecting rails_log_stdout
     - Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets

       - -----> Discovering process types
     - Procfile declares types      -> web, worker
     - Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake

       - -----> Compiled slug size: 31.2MB
       - -----> Launching... done, v7
     - http://fruttella.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

       - heroku ps:scale web=1
       - Scaling web processes... done, now running 1

but after command **heroku ps** i have :
 `== web:`bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
 web.1: crashed 2013/03/05 16:33:27 (~ 3m ago)

And my ror application not start on heroku. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the migrations?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: After migrate i have : Don't know how to build task 'db:migate'

Comment: sorry, typo: `heroku run rake db:migrate`.  Corrected in the answer

Comment: on localhost I did rake db:seed for correct work. Maybe try this in heroku?

Comment: Yes, run `heroku run rake db:seed` and any other rake tasks you need to run.

Comment: in my log files: `013-03-05T15:24:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 10158
2013-03-05T15:24:43+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': invalid argu (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)

Comment: Which file do you want to see?

Comment: Server was started after add to Procfile : web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV , that start server.